# Jboss exception : javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unsupported content type: text/plain. Response: Internal Server Error/500

Tags: web-services, soap, jboss, jax-ws, wsimport

when I try to make request to a webservice I got the following error:

java.io.IOException:Could not transmit message

org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker. javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unsupported content type: text/plain. Response: Internal Server Error/500.

Do you know what could be the reason ?

WSDL java classes have been autogenerated with wsimport jvm command

regards

Comment: A component in the process has set the http `content-type` header to `text/plain`. What you should have there is `text/xml`. You need to trace the path of your SOAP request to identify at what specific point this is happening

Comment: I autogenerate classes with wsimport but seems something was missing because I autogenerate again with apache axis through webservices options with intellij idea, and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I autogenerate classes using another webservice implementation. I used AXIS instead of wsimport.
In the header of my autogenerated classes I have this text:

- This file was auto-generated from WSDL
- by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.

hope this helps to others facing the same problem as me

cheers